# SQL query that joins, filters by a specific element and returns complimentary records

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have 2 tables:

sites: this table represents a list of sites and some information about them
tasks: a table that assigns tasks to specific employees by site and by date

What I need is a query that gets all the sites not already in tasks for a specific date.

The closest I have gotten is the following:

```
SELECT 
    sites.ID, 
    sites.name 
FROM 
    sites
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.site_ID = sites.ID
WHERE tasks.ID IS NULL
```

This query returns the sites not already listed in the entire tasks table and not just the ones on a particular date.

I am relatively new to these more complex queries so bear with me as I am probably missing something obvious. I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around the problem.

To reiterate if table1 is sites and table2 is tasks I need a query that gets me all the items in table1 that are not already listed in table2 for specific date.

Comment: Its really unhelpful for you to ask about querying a database without providing a sample data structure. Please consider That

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all the site/date combinations that *have not* been assigned.

If so, you do this with a `CROSS JOIN` to generate all possible combinations and then some method -- say `LEFT JOIN/WHERE` -- to remove the ones that exist:

```
select s.id as site_id, d.date
from sites s cross join
     (select distinct t.date from tasks) d left join
     tasks t
     on t.site_id = s.id and t.date = d.date
where t.site_id is null;
```

If you are only looking for one date, then a simpler query is:

```
select s.*
from sites s
where not exists (select 1
                  from tasks t
                  where t.site_id = s.id and t.date = $date
                 );
```

For multiple dates, the first method is simpler -- you can replace the `d` subquery with a list of dates that you care about.

Comment: The second one is exactly what I needed. I knew I probably needed a subquery but wasn't quite sure how to implement it. 

I had forgotten you could do the 'where not exists'

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery :

```
SELECT 
    s.ID,
    s.name
FROM sites s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tasks WHERE site_ID = s.ID and date = ?)
```

Where the question mark is the date you want to check for.